# css only parallax scrolling with sticky menu

Tags: html, css

I know that `background-attachment: fixed` exits and the problem with mobile devices and how to solve those using `stick`. But I'm looking for a CSS solution for parallax scrolling where the background slightly shifts.

There are various CSS only solutions that work by setting the height of the parallax container to `height: 100vh`:

```
.parallax-container {
    height: 100vh;
    perspective: 300px;
}
```

And using something like `transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);` on the a `parallax-layer` to achive the shifting.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <main class="parallax-container">
     <section>some content</section>
     <div class="parallax-content">
        <div class="parallax-layer-1"></div>
     </div>
     <section>some content</section>
  </main>
</body>
```

While this itself works fine, I start to get problems when I want to apply `position: sticky` to the header, because `height: 100vh` on the `.parallax-container` container breaks the sticky behavior because now sticky thinks that `parallax-container` has only the height `100vh`.

`position: fixed` won't work for the `header` if I don't know the actual height of the header.

I also could make `.parallax-container` scrollable and the body not scrollable, but then the scrollbar is below the header which is also annoying.

I know that I could solve that using JavaScript, but is there a CSS only way to have `sticky` header and a 3D parallax effect?